# Concurrent build of the same build definition with tfs

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

What's the best way to allow only one build of the same build definition at a time?
I searched but found nothing related to concurrent build of the same build definition.

Comment: What is the reason, that you can't run it in parallel? A suggestion would be to have only one build agent for this build definition, so if there is already a build running, all others will wait till this is finished.

Comment: Yes it can't run in parallel. That's what I thought: playing with agent filter to only send build to one agent. I was hoping there was an alternative like in TeamCity(http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD6/Configuring+General+Settings#ConfiguringGeneralSettings-Limitthenumberofsimultaneouslyrunningbuilds)